# Find call returning outdated info immediately after Save

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In my application, an action takes some user generated input and uses it to update an entry in the database.

The relevant code resembles the following:

```
$this->Model->save($data);
$result = $this->Model->findById($id);
```

The problem is that the contents of $result are outdated.  That is, $result contains the record as it was *before* the save.

I'm assuming that the entry just isn't updated until the function returns.  However, I can't do the obvious

```
$result = $this->Model->save($data);
```

because this method does not preserve relationships.  In this case, the model belongs to another model.  I need to be able to get the updated record *and* the record it belongs to.

Comment: So then _when_ _is_ it being updated (don't just assume, figure it out)? And what DBMS/Storage Engine you are using? Also please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly!

Comment: Are you sure the record is actually being updated? Try wrapping it in an `if($this->Model->save($data)) { $result = $this->Model=>...}`

Comment: The record is being updated.  The next time I refresh the page, the correct data is returned.

Answer (score 0):

See if

```
$result = $this->Model->findById($id);
```

is loading from the cache, not the database.

Take a look at:
http://fredericiana.com/2007/09/05/cakephp-delete-cached-models-on-database-change/
http://snook.ca/archives/cakephp/delete_cached_models/

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've never liked Cake's magic find functions. I find them difficult to add extra conditions/joins/etc to and I much prefer to type a few more lines and get something specific that I can easily adjust.

Sounds in this case like the magic find function is returning from the cache, and you should try a regular find call instead:

```
$this->Model->save($data);
$result = $this->Model->find('first', array('conditions' => array('id' => $id)));
```

However, you should try and narrow down your problem and find out exactly what it is for future reference. You could try manually [clearing the cache](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Cache.html#clearing-the-cache) before you do your magic find and see if you get the correct response:

```
$this->Model->save($data);
Cache::clear();
$result = $this->Model->findById($id);
```

Another unlikely yet possible option is that your `$id` variable may not be pointing to the correct model row, and your save might be creating a new one so that when you `findById($id)` the `$id` is different to the ID of the row you've just saved/created. In this case, it's worth doing a `debug($id)` or `$this->log('ID is: ' . $id, 'my_test_log');` before and after your safe or at intervals through your code to work out what is happening and where.

Comment: I'm currently working in a table with a single entry, so I know I've got the right ID.  I'll try your other solution, but I've already found a workaround.

Comment: Okay, so, switching to a normal find produces the same results.  So does clearing the cache, which surprises me.